# angular directive: switch between two templates dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am trying to create a directive named `availableTo` that can switch between two different templates depending on some message. For example, if the field is an `input` with the `ng-model` directive, I would first need to change it to read-only using the `<span>` tag. So far, my code can switch the view to read-only, but I cannot seem to switch it back to `input`:

```
var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: linkerFn,
      replace: true
    };

function linkerFn(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        var clonedElement = angular.copy(element);
        var preOuterHTML = clonedElement[0].outerHTML; //this can save the <input> field html code

        scope.$on('mode_changed', function() {
          var curUserRole = userservices.getUserRole();

          if (attrs.availableTo == curUserRole) {
                var e = $compile(preOuterHTML)(scope);
                element.replaceWith(e);
          } else {
                var template = '<span>' + ngModelCtrl.$viewValue + '</span>';
                var e = $compile(template)(scope);
                element.replaceWith(e);
          }

        }); //scope.$on
    } //linkerFn
```

For an `input` field:

```
  <input name="test1" class="form-control" ng-model="name" placeholder="Name 1" available-to="ADMIN"/>
```

I also noticed that once I change the template in the `else` block above, the element re-renders, and the `preOuterHTML` does not contain the original element html any more. This seems to be mission impossible to me, but I would like to hear some expert opinions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element.replaceWith(e);` Don't do that. In Angular, if you find yourself attempting to modify the DOM directly, you are by definition doing it wrong.  You gotta sit back and let Angular do the work.

If you need to replace a directive's entire template, a fairly straightforward approach is to use ng-include with a scope variable containing the desired conditional `templateUrl`, e.g.

```
var directive = {
  // ...
  template: '<div ng-include="myTemplateUrl"></div>',
  link: function(scope, el) {
    if (/* whatever */) {
      scope.myTemplateUrl="templates/foo.html";
    } else {
      //...etc
    }
  },
};
```

(This does add an extra DOM node to the tree, but that's generally harmless.)

It sounds like in your case you may not need to go that far, though; a simple `ng-if` inside your template is probably enough to swap between your read-only `<span>` and `<input>`.

Comment: _"if you find yourself attempting to modify the DOM directly, you are by definition doing it wrong"_ - So you really suggest that Angular itself does it wrong? And whose definition are you referring to?

Comment: @zeroflagL I think the whole point of that statement is that *only* angular should modify the DOM.  99% of the time, people use `element` methods because they don't know of the right way to architect the application in such a way that angular can instead. The answer has provided a better way for this use case perfectly.

Comment: @Daniel Beck, thanks so much for the solution. As I am trying to make the directive as generic as possible, I think I would need to create a template for all possible input fields such as `input`, `select`, `checkbox`. There seems to be just no direct way of caching the original element template in Angular.

Comment: @Claies I agree with most of what you wrote. Yet the idea that only Angular should modify the DOM is even worse than the bad practices you mentioned. That was kind of the point my comment. The OP's requirements almost cry for a custom directive. Writing `ng-if` and `span` a few hundred times is not a feasible solution. And templates don't even come up in this use case.

Comment: @zeroflagL I honestly don't understand what you're objecting to. As Claies described, I was saying that *only* Angular should modify the DOM (via, yes, templates in custom directives, as in my answer.) Bypassing Angular to overwrite parts of the DOM directly always leads to problems.

Comment: @TonyGW Hard to be sure this is the best approach without more detail about what you're trying to do, but you might consider using `ng-transclude` to contain the "original" html, and have this custom directive conditionally hide the transcluded portion and reveal the read-only `<span>` instead.

Comment: The whole point - well, mostly - of directives is to manipulate the DOM. When you say that only Angular should modify the DOM then you ignore the fact that Angular does this with .... directives. Just because the framework provides a basic set of them doesn't mean you shouldn't write  your own ones. Directives are directives, no matter where they come from. There are lots of use cases where Angular's directives are not enough and custom directives are not only a choice but a must. And in this case by custom directives I explicitly mean manipulating the DOM via jQuery (lite) or similar tools.

Comment: @zeroflagL  Yes, of course angular manipulates the DOM using directives, and of course we need to write our own directives! That's exactly what I was saying!  But the correct way to control the DOM is with logic in the directive template.  Using directives as fancy wrappers for jQuery or jqlite-based DOM manipulation kind of misses the point of using Angular, in my opinion -- you end up doing a lot of work that the framework would be perfectly happy to take care of for you.

Comment: You can judge the value of your theory by a simple thought experiment: Assume that there is no `ngRepeat`, or `ngIf`, which actually did not exist in earlier versions of Angular. Moreover Angular exposes the `$compile` service and `angular.element`, both of which would be completely unnecessary according to your theory. And the logic in templates comes from directives. Directives that directly modify the DOM tree ... BTW: You did not provide a single argument against DOM manipulation so far. And as for your last sentence: It's the other way round. You can **save** a lot of work.

Comment: Okay, I think we're talking past each other here.  Let's just leave it as you and I have very different approaches to the framework.